# Trying to use BEM methodology, am I on the right track?

Tags: html, css, bem

Trying to use BEM methodology, am I on the right track?

````
            <header className="first-section__header">
                <nav className="first-section__header__navigation">
                    <ul className="first-section__header__navigation__list">
                        <li className="first-section__header__navigation__item"></li>
                        <li className="first-section__header__navigation__item"></li>
                        <li className="first-section__header__navigation__item"></li>
                        <li className="first-section__header__navigation__item"></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <button className="button first-section__header__btn">Enter</button>
            </header>
        </section>```
````

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good fit for Stack Overflow as you aren't asking a specific question. [The Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

in bem method you can go 2 level.

```
.parent__child__secondChild //correct
.parent__child__secondChild__thirdChild //not correct.
```

[for more details about bem.](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/#:%7E:text=The%20Block%2C%20Element%2C%20Modifier%20methodology,CSS%20in%20a%20given%20project.)